# Cogs Not Working In Discord.py And commands also not working

Tags: python, discord.py

I've created a discord bot using python but cogs are not working in my bot Please Tell Me Is There Any Mistake in this code

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

import os

from help_cog import help_cog

from music_cog import music_cog

intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='=', intents=intents)

bot.remove_command("help")

async def load_extensions():

    await bot.load_extension("help_cog.py")

    await bot.load_extension("music_cog.py")

bot.run('Token')
```

This is my first file bot.py

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

class help_cog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):

        self.bot = bot

        self.help_message = """
```

General Commands:

=help - Displays All Avilable Commands

=p  - Finds The Song On Youtube And Plays It In Your Current Channel

=q - Shows The Music Queue

=skip - Skips The Currently Playing Song

=clear - Stops The Music And Clear The Queue

=leave - Disconnect The Bot From Voice Channel

=pause - Pauses The Currently Playing Song

=resume - Resumes The Currently Paused Song

```
"""

        self.text_channel_text = []

        

    @commands.Cog.listener()

    async def on_ready(self):

        for guild in self.bot.guilds:

            for channel in guild.text_channels:

                self.text_channel_text.append(channel)

        

        await self.send_to_all(self.help_message)

        

    async def send_to_all(self, msg):

        for text_channel in self.text_channel_text:

            await text_channel.send(msg)

            

    @commands.command(name='help', help="Displays All Avilable Commands")

    async def help(self, ctx):

        await ctx.send(self.help_message)

            

        

async def setup(bot):

    await bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
```

This is my cog file help_cog.py

There is no output, but it also Doesn't print that bot is ready or something

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You're never *calling* that `load_extensions` function, so you're not loading your cogs. It's good that you *made it*, but you aren't using it.

Discord.py can't smell that it's supposed to call that function, nor that it's supposed to load your cog...

Comment: The migration guide has an example of how to do it: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous